# Download Speed: Ubuntu 14.04 vs Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, windows-8.1

I am facing a curious case: I have 2 PCs, one Windows 8.1 and one Ubuntu 14.04 machine (both single boot only).

I can't figure out the reason why my Ubuntu PC is getting download speed of 60 to 70 KB/s while my windows PC gets only 25 to 30 KB/s. Both are at the same place using the same network (Wifi) and downloading the same file. **I tested them separately (by Downloading 1.1 GB Ububtu 15.04 iso file over Web browser), first downloading in Windows and then cancelling it and then downloading in Ubuntu (I tested 3-4 times).**

Could there be some reason why I am observing this behaviour (since a week) ?

Comment: Please specify how you did the tests: are you downloading from external websites or from another Server / SAN in the same WLAN, which protocol (HTTP, FTP or Windows File Share), how big are the files.

Comment: @user3767013 plz see the edit

Comment: Are they downloading the same file from an external web site through HTTP?

Comment: @user3767013 yes

Comment: So you have two different machines with possibly different brand/type/model wireless cards. Guaruteed different drivers (even if the same model wirelesscard is used) and you get different speeds. This makes diagnosing hard since we only have apples and oranges to compare.  If you could boot a liveCD (from live CD for Ubuntuy on the windows PC or vice versa) and the speeds stays the same and the cards where the ame then it gets interesting. But right now there is not much which we can 'solve'.

Comment: I agree with Hennes, shove a live ubuntu CD into the windows box and test the exact same file downloads. Do them several times and make sure you delete the cache each time so your not using a cached version. That way hardware is the same and only OS is different

Comment: Which program are you using for the download?

Comment: @badge-be Chrome in Windows, Firefox in Ubuntu. But my main point is a 2 times difference in speed (!!!) should not be possible.

Comment: Why don't you try firefox for windows?

Comment: @badge-be I have observed the same behaviour in Chrome on Ubuntu. I don't think it would be an application issue, Could it be some other issue like router thing ?

Comment: Try [free download manager](http://www.freedownloadmanager.org/) on windows and see what you get. It uses multithreaded downloads.

Comment: Windows may be throttling network performance so multithreading should help.

Comment: @badge-be I will try that. But how culd Windows be throttling network performance, I don't have any network intensive apps runnning.

Comment: I don't know why the following happens, but when Android downloads something it takes priority over windows on the network, but it does not do the same for Linux.

Comment: @badge-be Why android takes a priority over windows ? On the same network ?

Comment: I don't know why, but it does, when the connection is shared on a wifi network (I have only tried wifi).